# How to customize the Jackson serializer for Spring SQS

Tags: spring, jackson, amazon-sqs

How do you customize the Jackson JSON serializer for SQS? I've googled around, but so far everything I've found is related to the Spring web stuff, and there doesn't seem to be any way to get a hold of a reference to the serializer that Spring SQS uses, so that I can add my custom types (Java 8 Date stuff)

Comment: What is this Spring SQS you speak of?

Comment: The spring cloud SQS service: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sqs_support

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had a look at the source code of `spring-cloud-aws` to see how the Jackson object mapper is being instantiated, see here: [QueueMessagingTemplate.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/core/QueueMessagingTemplate.java).

It turns out that it has a constructor that takes in a `MessageConverter`, so you could do this:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringAwsMessagingConfig {

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate myMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQS amazonSqs, ResourceIdResolver resolver) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // configure the Jackson mapper as needed

        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setSerializedPayloadClass(String.class);
        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs, resolver, converter);
    }

}
```